# Web-based thumbnail image in 'Item Description' for a Python toolbox [ArcGIS 10.1]

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, python-toolbox, thumbnail

I'm using locally stored images as thumbnails in the Item Description for a python toolbox [ArcGIS 10.1].  I'd like to load the images from an online source so other users of the toolbox can still see the images.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Since you have to send them the toolbox (which should include the .pyt and .xml file(s)), wouldn't it be easiest to include the images in the folder and send all of that?

Comment: Coworkers typically copy the .pyt through ArcCatalog across a network, so the .xml files are copied automatically.